# What are the adodb record set options we need to use for loading data from SQL in short time in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

We are working on ADODB.RecordSet open for executing the query and storing the records into recordset. We have used cursor location as AdUseServer, CursorType as AdOpenStatic and LockType as AdLockReadOnly and it is taking 1 min 11 sec for loading and getting the record count for 900k records but in RDODB it is taking just 24 sec to fetch the data into record set.

We have operations like recordset.movefirst, recordset.movelast and recordset.update for the record set.

Do we have any other combinations to reduce the fetch time?

Comment: (Assuming SQL Server) Its highly likely this is an issue with the SQL query & it's cached plan rather than any issue with RDO vs ADO.  Its likely that the RDO version is using a better plan than the ADO version (differences in the connection options sent by each library can cause separate plans).  Clear the plan cache or restart the server & run the ADO version first and see if it behaves like the RDO version,  if so its usually parameter sniffing that is the root cause.

Comment: I'm a bit irritated by mentioning rs.MoveFirst, rs.MoveLast and then stating "getting the record **count**" (emphasise mine). Are you really only looking for the record **count**? If so, I suggest a SQL statement like `SELECT COUNT(<integer column>) AS RecCount FROM <table>[<WHERE clause if needed>]...` and then retrieving the count with rs.Fields("RecCount").Value.

Comment: Not sure how you can update your recordset if you're using a Readonly lock. What do you mean by fetch - you talk about MoveFirst MoveLast and RecordCount - or are you talking about the actual Open of the recordset?